# How during run time web-application uses servlet-api.jar which is different in project's pom.xml?

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, servlets, pom.xml

I have created a simple web application using Spring MVC, and one of the dependency in pom.xml is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The version of `servlet-api` is `2.5` with scope as `provided`, hence when I deploy the web application in tomcat, the `servlet-api` would be "provided" by the container. This is clear to me.

My doubt is that in tomcat, the name of this dependency is simply `servlet-api.jar` and with no version info; whereas in pom.xml we mention with the version name as well, hence the effective name of the jar file becomes `servlet-api-2.5.jar`.

So at run time in tomcat, doesn't it look for exact name of the jar file? How is it able to run?

Any explanation would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your web app, running on Tomcat, will **not** look for a specific JAR file (by name or by anything else).

Instead, it will use the classpath to discover *classes*.

Whether those classes were added to the classpath from a JAR file named `servlet-api-2.5.jar` or a JAR file named `servlet-api.jar` is irrelevant at runtime.